# Polythiophenes versus Polypyrroles

Tags: organic-chemistry, semiconductors

I've been searching for the differences in semiconductor properties of polythiophene (pth) and polypyrrole (pry).
Most resources just state their ability to form polarons and can be doped. However, I wanted to find out if there were differences in band gaps or any other differences due to the change of heteroatom (sorry for the vagueness)

Comment: Consider that these type of materials have properties (of all kinds) spanning broad ranges as for are highly dependent on preparation or even batch. What I can easily tell you is that PTh is the working horse for a huge number of groups, while PPy found much less interest. Moreover there is a mess in terminology. For instance you mention band gap, there could be already different ways to interpret that. Whatever difference you might find will be due to the fact that Py is less aromatic than Th. In short, to date, PPy does not seem to be of much interest *at least in organic electronics*.

Comment: A crucial difference is that neutral polythiophene (in particular re-P3HT) is a reality. The Py based counterpart, to my knowledge, has still to come to existence. One probably need a chapter to discuss why it is. Likely it all starts on the different reactivity of Th and Py themselves, or that of their dimers trimers... Chemistry of Py conjugated systems is anyways interesting in biological systems, from blood cells to pigments). Sorry but I can't answer in coincise form because of what these comments say.